# SQL query stops working if column repeats

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Datagridview like this:

```
Model  day1  day2  day3
 car    1     2      4
 bike   2     3      5
 ship   6     1      7
```

Then i save it in my database table like this:

```
    date   model   qty id
    day1    car     1   1
    day2    car     2   2
    day3    car     4   3
    day1    bike    2   4
    day2    bike    3   5
    day3    bike    5   6
    day1    ship    6   7
    day2    ship    1   8
    day3    ship    7   9
```

Then using this query:

```
Select Min(id) As id,model From table Group By model order by id
```

i get the list of models in the same order as i had them in the datagridview:

```
car
bike
ship
```

The problem comes when i save 2 models with the same name in the table and then execute my query,i expect to get this:

```
1 car
2 bike
3 ship
4 car
```

but instead i get this:

```
1 car
2 bike
3 ship
```

The second proble with the current design i have is, if somehow i manage to retrieve the list as in the datagrid view:

```
car
bike
ship
car
```

How im going to know which quantities are from the first "car" and which ones are from the last "car" so i can put them in the datagridview back again.

In resume, i want to show in the datagrid the info in the same order i had it when i save it, but i dont know if the problem is the design of my table or the query im doing.

Example:

Saving this in my table, and then doing a query to get the same info in the same format:

```
   Model  day1  day2  day3
     car    1     2      4
     bike   2     3      5
     ship   6     1      7
     car    1     2      4
```

Comment: what do you mean `when i save 2 models with the same name in the table and then execute my query` where are the 2 models?

Comment: What you need is a primary key in your model table.

Comment: What is a "name"?  I don't see it anywhere in your data and your original data has multiple rows with the same model.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your query, you are grouping by the `model`
This means it will get the minimum Id of all the cars of that model, so you have car twice, but it only shows once because it groups all records of `model` car and selects the minimum Id which will be 1

Try this:

```
Select Count(id) As ModelCount,model From table Group By model order by id
```

on your dataset with the four cars and you will find that it will return the following:

```
ModelCount | model
         2 | car
         1 | bike
         1 | ship
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, this is a gaps-and-island problem, sort-of.  Actually, it is a data representation problem.  Why are you storing the data with a single id instead of a row id and column id?

Given the way you are sorting the data, you can subtract a sequence to identify groups.  Then you can `group by` and get the original rows:

```
select model
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by model order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by model, (id - seqnum)
order by min(id);
```

But let me emphasize that if you want row/column information, then that is what you should be storing in the database.